# What happens if flight issues delay my arrival to the UK by less then 24 hours with a Tier 2 Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I have a Tier 2 Visa that expires on June 2nd.  This is my initial trip in my opening 30 day window and due to weather delay's in the states, I might arrive on June 3rd.  Do I have options to explain my situation?  Or do I need to start over?

Comment: Are you already at the airport? Or did your airline notify you of a delay?

Answer (score 14):

You must not arrive in the UK outside of the validity of your entry vignette. I do not believe that you will be granted entry on the basis of your Tier 2 visa if you arrive even only a day late. [UKVI makes clear the onus is on the applicant to ensure they arrive in the validity period](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entry-clearance-vignettes-ecb09/ecb09-entry-clearance-vignettes-types-safeguarding-and-validity#ecb94-validity-of-entry-clearance), so travelling to arrive on the last day was always going to be risky.

However, all is not lost. You don’t need to apply for a new Tier 2 visa. [You need to apply for a “transfer of conditions” to get a new entry vignette with a new validity period](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transferring-a-visa-to-a-new-passport-ecb17/transferring-a-visa-ecb17#ecb173-replacing-a-30-day-short-validity-travel-vignette). Assuming you are applying in the US, [this will cost $204](https://visa-fees.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/usa/usd/other/other-fees/vignette-transfertransfer-of-a-valid-visa-vignette-to-a-new-passport-or-replace-a-loststolen-document).